# Couldn't pass params to ticket purchase action

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I am building an application where a user can find an event and buy a ticket to that event. Here are my files:

**tickets/new.html.erb**:

```
<%= form_tag('/ticket/finish') do %>
  <% @event.ticket_types.each do |ticket_type| %>
    <tr>
      <td><%= ticket_type.name %></td>
      <td> <%= number_to_currency(ticket_type.price, unit: 'VND ', precision: 0) %></td>
      <td> <%= select_tag(:quantity, options_for_select(0..10)) %></td>
    </tr>
    <br>
  <% end %>
  <p>
    <%= submit_tag 'Purchase Ticket',  class: 'btn btn-primary' %>
  </p>
<% end %>
```

**tickets_controller.rb**:

```
class TicketsController < ApplicationController

  def new
    @event = Event.find(params[:event_id])
    @ticket = Ticket.new
  end

  def purchase

  end
end
```

**event.rb**:

```
class Event < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :user
  belongs_to :venue
  belongs_to :category
  has_many :ticket_types


  validates_associated :ticket_types
  validates_presence_of :user

  validates_presence_of  :name, :extended_html_description, :hero_image_url
  # validates_presence_of :venue, :category

  validates_uniqueness_of :name,scope: [:venue_id, :starts_at]

  def has_ticket_types?
    !!self.ticket_types.present?
  end
end
```

**ticket_types.rb**:

```
class TicketType < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :event

  validates_presence_of :name, :price, :max_quantity

  validates_uniqueness_of :name, scope: :event_id
end
```

**routes.rb**:

```
Rails.application.routes.draw do
  devise_for :users
  root 'events#index'

  get '/yourevents', to: 'events#user_events'

  resources :events do
    resources :tickets
  end

  get '/ticket/purchase', to: 'tickets#purchase'

  get 'ticket/finish', to: 'tickets#finish'

  resources :events do
    resources :ticket_types
  end

  resources :venues
end
```

My goal is I want when user click the 'purchase ticket' button, it will lead them to a page that shows them the ticket types, and the quantity of those ticket types they have just bought. However, I have no idea how can I pass those params in my purchase action since I don't have a ticket model. Could anybody here give me some hint or guide me to the right direction? Thank you in advance.

Comment: Firstly you should regroup your models and associations. `ticket_type` model is unnecessary and it looks more like a `ticket` model to me. And you have the `form` linked to wrong action.

Comment: Thank you for your suggestion. However, the ticket_type model is one of the requirements for this project. Since after creating the event, a user needs to create a ticket type for this event, otherwise it will not be shown publicly. And could you tell me why my form is linked to the wrong action? The scenario is when a user clicks the button `purchase ticket`, it will submit all the data to action `purchase`, then it will save all of those data, and show them to the user in the finish page.

Comment: The form is linked to `/ticket/finish` action which should be `/ticket/purchase`.